# Symfony, Cannot retrieve record from table

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony I cannot retrieve a record from a table using a **find()**, but I can using **createQuery()**? This is happening randomly on my tables in my project. The data just seem to become unaccessable using symfony find(), findBy() etc, but I can use dql???

Why is this happening? Has anyone ever had this happen? I cannot figure this out. Thanks for helping!

**Test I've Ran:** I've created a similar table using the exact same entity fields and imported the data into the table and it works absolutely fine. Why has this table just stopped responding to Symfony's request?

**This Works**

```
    $dql = "SELECT co FROM WIC\CommonBundle\Entity\CustomOptions co WHERE co.account=:account_id AND co.option_field=:value";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $query->setParameters(array(
        'value' => 'reorder_reason',
    ));
    $customOptionValue = $query->getResult();
    echo count($customOptionValue); // equals 3
```

**This DOES NOT Work - Exact same variables are passed in**

```
    $customOptionValue = $em->getRepository('WICCommonBundle:CustomOptions')->findBy(
    array(
           "option_field"=>"reorder_reason",
        )
    );
    echo count($customOptionValue); // equals 0
```

**Here is my CustomOptions entity:**

```
namespace WIC\CommonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * CustomOptions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="accountFieldValueOptions", columns={"account_id", "option_value", "option_field"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WIC\CommonBundle\Entity\CommonRepository")
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class CustomOptions
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string $option_value
     *
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     * @ORM\Column(name="option_value", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Option Value Should Not Be Blank")
     */
    private $option_value;

    /**
     * @var string $option_field
     *
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     * @ORM\Column(name="option_field", type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true)
     */
    private $option_field;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    protected $account;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set account
     *
     * @param \WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account $account
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setAccount(\WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account $account = null)
    {
        $this->account = $account;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get account
     *
     * @return \WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account
     */
    public function getAccount()
    {
        return $this->account;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return CustomOptions
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return CustomOptions
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set deletedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deletedAt
     * @return CustomOptions
     */
    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deletedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get option_value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionValue()
    {
        return $this->option_value;
    }

    /**
     * Set option_value
     *
     * @param string $option_value
     * @return CustomOptions
     */
    public function setOptionValue($option_value)
    {
        $this->option_value = $option_value;
    }

    /**
     * Get option_field
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionField()
    {
        return $this->option_field;
    }

    /**
     * Set option_field
     *
     * @param string $option_field
     * @return CustomOptions
     */
    public function setOptionField($option_field)
    {
        $this->option_field = $option_field;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return CustomOptions
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
```

Comment: I am running to a meeting and looked at this less than 20 seconds, but maybe `"account"=>$account->getId()`?

Comment: I removed the account id, it has no effect upon the issue.

Comment: Nobody asked you to remove anything. He was pointing out that you're looking it up via the object instead of the ID. in findBy methods the key in the array is only used for the mapping in doctrine, i.e. account maps to account_id, so it's doing a where account_id=YOUR_PHP_OBJECT which does not make sense.

Comment: I don't care if no one asked me to not remove anything, the variable has no bearing to the cause or the solution and obviously has created two inaccurate response to the question. Cheers.

Comment: Well the beauty of this is now that you've learned TWO things you were doing entirely wrong instead of only one :p Cheers sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ID instead of the entire object

I.e.

```
$customOptionValue = $em->getRepository('WICCommonBundle:CustomOptions')->findBy(array(
    "account"=>$account->getId(), 
    "option_field"=>"reorder_reason",
));
```

Edit: it's your failure to follow the coding standards expected by symfony that caused this issue for you:

`Use camelCase, not underscores, for variable, function and method names`

`private $option_field` should become `private $optionField` and you should adjust any functions you created to reflect this. Then your findBy array will use `"optionField"=>"reorder_reason"`

Comment: I removed the account id, it has no effect upon the issue.

Comment: I don't care if no one asked me to not remove anything, the variable has no bearing to the cause or the solution and obviously has created two inaccurate response to the question. Cheers. I "literally" copied and pasted your code and it did not solve the issue at all.

Comment: Edited answer as the error is a result of you not mapping the variable within the naming conventions expected by symfony2.

Comment: It doesn't work. This is a much deeper issue than what you are proposing. I've tried what you have suggested and there is not the solution.

Comment: I've created a similar table using the exact same entity fields and imported the data into the table and it works absolutely fine. Why has this table just stopped responding to Symfony's request??? Things that make us go hmmmm???

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using soft `@Gedmo\SoftDeleteable`. Can you please check if the record that exists and can not be retreived does not have `deletedAt` set?

Doctrine queries are ignoring record, where deletedAt is set. But lets say "not doctrine queries" would still be able to find these records.